# How to use jspdf CDN in a react project

Tags: reactjs, cdn, jspdf

I am developing a ReactJS application that must produce a PDF file. I want to use jspdf so I added the following line to the header of my index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Then I went to the javascript file containing my actual component and I wrote

```
var pdf=new jsPDF();
```

Obtaining the error: '`jsPDF is not defined`'. So I added this line at the top of the file containing the component:

```
import {jsPDF} from 'jspdf';
```

This has led to the npm error `Module not found: Can't resolve 'jspdf' in 'C:\my-app\src'`. So I should I use a CDN in react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time you are transpiling your code, your node env knows nothing about jsPDF that it's included in the final page. You need to ignore this.

Define it as a [global](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals). Put this comment at the top of your JS file:

```
/* global jsPDF */
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is replacing `jsPDF` with `window.jsPDF` like in this example:

```
var pdf=new window.jsPDF();
```